# Why sizeof char returns 4?

Tags: c++, variables, structure, sizeof

I wanted to do a sending the disconnect packet with disconnect type as one byte.
I did structures, etc.

```
struct NET_PROTO_HEADER
{
    unsigned int mLength;
    unsigned short mPacketGroup;
    unsigned short mPacketType;
};

struct NET3_SERVER_DISCONNECT : public NET_PROTO_HEADER
{
    unsigned char mType;
};
```

But when I try to send it, sizeof method returns size 12 and it's sended with addonitional nulls at end.

```
NET3_SERVER_DISCONNECT data;
    data.mLength = 9;
    data.mPacketGroup = 3;
    data.mPacketType = 100;
    data.mType = 0xcb;
                    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer((char*)&data, sizeof(data)),
                        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

What Im doing wrong here ?
Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: If you expected size 9, you have forgotten about structure padding. If you expected size 1, you have forgotten about inheritance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i expected size 9 :D.

Comment: If you want to send packed data, you may have to pack it yourself.  Relying on structure layout can lead to interoperability problems between platforms, or between different ABIs on the same platform (eg. 32-bit and 64-bit x86 code, for example.)